# IOS Image memory usage

Tags: ios, image, memory, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

I want to know how does iOS utilizes memory when displaying images...

for instance:
I have an image that its 2000w, 2000h, but the iphone, ipod in this particular case has a rectangle of 460x920 (just an example)... if the image is just visible for the rectangle of the iOS device, i know for sure that memory is being used, but what happens to the rest of the image that is NOT CURRENTLY drawn in the rectangle? is that memory being consumed? or iOS is smart enough that is not using memory only for the drawn section? or is this considered as memory-leak?

I am wondering this because in some games you need longer scenarios with big images in which using parallaxnodes or anything similar helps. But I started to wonder how this affects my memory.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On iPhone 4 you have 512MB of RAM. It's shared between CPU and GPU, which means Video RAM consumes a part of it.

If you are talking about a `UIImage` allocated 2000 by 2000 pixels. Even if it's off-screen, it **DOES** consume RAM. To be precise, it consumes 2000*2000*4, around 16MB. This is managed by Objective-c runtime. This is a fairly large amount. As far as I know, the maximum size of a `UIImage` on the 4 series devices is 2048x2048, and 1024x1024 on 3 series.

The viewing rectangle, or the screen you are talking about, is a part of the Video RAM. Typical displaying procedure involves compositing the image in Video RAM so that the graphics hardware can display it.

Therefore, you have two copies of the image inside this 512MB of RAM. One you can load and modify by code (RAM), the other, smaller one for displaying (VRAM). Though in VRAM, only the size of the screen is used.

And no, this isn't memory leak.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what is the best way to handle this type of situation then? Because obviously I don't want all that memory to be used just because I need a big background image for my game(So making animations will be a problem)... how can i just use the memory I need for that moment? instead of loading ALL the image in the memory. 
The person that gave an answer as well, said "You can use things like CATiledLayer to better manage the image." is that the best solution for this situation?

Comment: Game images tend to be small. I mean, you'd better revise your design. You may find ``CATiledLayer`` a bit magic though. Check out http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/ . It basically works like Google Map in early stage. A large image is split into smaller tiles, and because it's too large, loading from a resource bundle tile by tile on demand is the only viable solution.

Comment: Exactly thats what i am looking for...and the reason i need this big image is because i need a BIG landspace area, like for example if you've played fieldrunners, cloud patrol, Sentinel, chono trigger, etc. well games that have biiig loong landscape images for their game, i need that but i didnt want to overload the device's memory thats why i was very concerned about this. 

Thanks ill check that out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the entire image in loaded into memory. You can use things like CATiledLayer to better manage the image.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that CATiledLayer.